# Trigger a button click with Javascript / jQuery when the

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Im trying to "click" on a search submit button with jquery. I use the "Instant Search & Suggest" plugin for wordpress, which generates the suggestions as you start typing the keywords in search field. It has an option if you enable in backend, when you click on the suggested keyword, it will take you directly to the specific single post page of that specific suggestion. I have disabled that, since instead of directly taking the user to the single post page, I need them to get to search results page. With that option disabled, all plugin does when you click on suggestion is inserts the suggested keyword (post title) into the search field, when you click on the suggestion.

Scenario is following: User starts typing keyword > plugin gives suggestions > User clicks on Suggestion >  Plugin inserts the clicked keyword / suggestion into the search field > script clicks on submit.

Besides the last part - "Script clicks on submit" - everything is working fine.

I tried couple different approaches.

```
    jQuery(".iss-result").on('click',function(){
         jQuery('#topsearchsubmit').trigger("click"); 
    });
```

Also tried this:

```
    $( ".iss-result" ).click(function() {
      $( "#topsearchform" ).submit();
    });
```

.iss-result is a class of suggestions in the dropdown under the search field. #topsearchform is the form ID and the #topsearchsubmit is the button ID of that form.

I have tried both jQuery(document).ready(function($) and without it, but no results in anyways. No any js errors when inspected either.

Can you please help me with this? How can I click on that search button, as soon as user clicks on the .iss-result li item?

Thank You

P.S. here is the search form HTML as asked

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="topsearchform" class="searchform group navbar-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
 <div class="input-group header-large-search-field login-popup">
     <label for="s"><span class="offscreen sr-only"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?></span></label>
     <input type="search" class="search-field form-control" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'placeholder' ) ?>" 
     value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button id="topsearchsubmit" class="btn btn-default2 btn-top-search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>

     <?php /* input type="image" alt="Submit search query" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/search-icon.png"> */ ?> 
 </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: share HTML as well

Comment: @guradio added the html of search form.

Comment: can you try `$(document).on('click','.iss-result',function(){})`?

Comment: The HTML you provided has no element with the `iss-result` class. Can you share the code that generates this element?

Comment: @trincot there is no iss-result in the search form itself. Its a regular WP search and the third party plugin called "Instant Search & Suggest", injects there html with jquery / ajax I guess. I have no idea how and where this code resides.

Comment: Maybe you can try different event then 'click', because when you click over '.iss-result', your form is still empty and you try to submit empty form. You should verify if the input element is filled, before submit form - maybe with some timeout or you can try to look the plugin code and find some other custom event.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helps you

```
jQuery(".iss-result").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
     var form=jQuery('#topsearchsubmit'); 
     $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                dataType:'json',
                success:  function (data) {



    },
            });
});
```

Comment: thanks for response. Unfortunately, that didnt work : ((

Answer (score 0):

As the elements with class `.iss-result` are created and destroyed while searching, they do not exist when you want to bind an event to them. You should use event delegation and listen for click events on a parent element, like the form. Filter the event sources to `.iss-result` and you should be able to listen to those clicks.

Secondly, you should probably not fire the submission immediately, as the plugin-in (which is also listening to these same clicks) needs to get time to put the selected value in the `input` element. So you should generate the submission click asynchronously (using `setTimeout`).

```
jQuery("#topsearchsubmit").on('click', '.iss-result', function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery('#topsearchsubmit').click();
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Im a very beginner at JS, but I see what you saying, it does make sense. However, I lack skills to code it. I copy pasted the code you gave but it didnt work, what should I modify in the code to make it work?

Comment: Without the actual application it is hard to see, but does the event handler run? Can you put some `alert('I get here');` statements just before and inside `setTimeout` to see if it gets there? Or if you are comfortable with `console.log`, then use that instead.